# How To Send Array of Object using FormData() From React Js To Nodejs, MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

State is like

```
state = {
courseTitle: "",
courseImage: "",
duration: "",
overView: "",
syllabus: [
  {
    title: "",
    description: "",
  },
 ],
};
```

And I'm submitting data using FormData() because i have image too

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("courseTitle", this.state.courseTitle);
fd.append("courseImage", this.state.courseImage);
fd.append("duration", this.state.duration);
fd.append("overView", this.state.overView);
fd.append("syllabus", this.state.syllabus);

this.props.addCourse(fd);
};
```

Everythings is fine except syllabus because it is in array, FormData send a value of syllabus,

```
syllabus:[object object]
```

Please Can anyone help me on how to send Array Data with the above state format, I'm using react and redux for backend nodejs, express and mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way i am aware of is to stringify the array and append. then parse on the backend.

```
// On frontend
fd.append("syllabus", JSON.stringify(this.state.syllabus));

// On backend
JSON.parse(syllabus)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to send (and aptly change the server-code or else check for the valid request spec with api documentation) values passed through `JSON.stringify`. In your example append the `syllabus` as `fd.append("syllabus", JSON.stringify(this.state.syllabus))`.